# Fitnesse RestFixture on Linux

Tags: linux, testing, rest, fitnesse

I've been using the [RestFixture](http://code.google.com/p/rest-fixture/) in [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) to test a REST service which is running under Tomcat. When Fitnesse is run on Linux (Redhat to be precise) the fixture doesn't pass any querystrings to Tomcat (the log entries prove this). However, the exact same fixture running through Fitnesse on a Windows machine works as expected.

Has anyone else tried this combination of operating system and fixture and had any experiences that may help?

Alternatively does anyone know of any good ways of bulk-testing REST services (in a way that a non-developer can create new tests).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just run across what appears to be this issue myself. I haven't tried on Windows but RestFixture is fairly definitely not populating my query parameters.

In fact, there's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/rest-fixture/issues/detail?id=13&can=1) on the RestFixture list about it.

Comment: Excellent spot! I posted that issue by the way! I forgot to update this question with it. The developer acknowledged there was an issue. I think I actually solved this by recompiling the latest code from SVN.

Answer (score 1):

the one described was in fact a bug. It is fixed in the trunk and it will be available in the next release coming at the end of April 09.